Why My Scss Files Generated Also .js extension? ( scss > css and js)
i have a webpack case. everything is good except just one thing.

for example
/styles/rapid.scss
exports like:
/styles/rapid.css
/styles/rapid.js
i dont wanna js file for scss. there is any solution?
my webpack project: https://github.com/cengizilhan/webpack-test-2/
webpack.common.js
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const paths = require('./paths')
const glob = require('glob')
const path = require('path')
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')


// Find all .scss files
const scssFiles = glob.sync(paths.src + '/styles/**/*.scss', {
    posix: true,
    dotRelative: true
})

// Debugging: Log the found SCSS files
console.log('Found SCSS files:', scssFiles)

// Create an entry object for the SCSS files
const styleEntries = scssFiles.reduce((entries, filePath) => {
    // Use the absolute path as the entry key
    console.log('filePath', filePath)
    console.log('entries', entries)
    const entryKey = filePath
        .replace('./Static/src/styles', './Static/styles')
        .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        .replace('.scss', '')
        
    entries[entryKey] = filePath
    return entries
}, {})

// Debugging: Log the generated style entries
console.log('Generated style entries:', styleEntries)


const scriptEntries = {
    './Static/scripts/aile/sawa.aile-app.min':
        paths.src + '/scripts/aile/sawa.aile-app.js',

    }

const styleTest = {
    '/Static/style/sawa': paths.src + '/styles/sawa.scss'
}

// Merge entries
console.log('styleentiries', styleEntries)
console.log('scriptEntries', scriptEntries)
const entries = {
    ...styleEntries,
    ...scriptEntries,
    //...styleTest
}
console.log('style test', styleTest)
module.exports = {
    // Where webpack looks to start building the bundle
    entry: entries,

    // Where webpack outputs the assets and bundles
    output: {
        path: paths.build,
        //path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    /*
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      parallel: true,
      extractComments: false,
      terserOptions: {
        nameCache: {},
        safari10: true,
        ie8: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
          drop_console: true,
        },
      },
    })],
  },*/
  /*
  watch:true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000,
    ignored: /node_modules/,
  },
  */
    // Customize the webpack build process
    plugins: [
        // Removes/cleans build folders and unused assets when rebuilding
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

        // Copies files from target to destination folder
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: paths.images,
                    to: paths.build + '/Static/images',
                    globOptions: {
                        ignore: ['*.DS_Store']
                    },
                    noErrorOnMissing: true
                },
                {
                    from: paths.fonts,
                    to: paths.build + '/Static/fonts',
                    globOptions: {
                        ignore: ['*.DS_Store']
                    },
                    noErrorOnMissing: true
                }
            ]
        }),

        // Generates an HTML file from a template
        // Generates deprecation warning: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1501
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'webpack Boilerplate',
            favicon: paths.src + '/images/favicon.png',
            template: paths.src + '/template.html', // template file
            filename: 'index.html' // output file
        })
    ],

    // Determine how modules within the project are treated
    module: {
        rules: [
            // JavaScript: Use Babel to transpile JavaScript files
            { test: /\.js$/, use: ['babel-loader'] },
      
            // Images: Copy image files to build folder
            { test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i, type: 'asset/resource' },
      
            // Fonts and SVGs: Inline files
            { test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/, type: 'asset/inline' },
          ],
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    resolve: {
        preferRelative: true,
        modules: [paths.src, 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
        alias: {
            '@': paths.src,
            assets: paths.build,
            jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/src/jquery')
            //react: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Static/src/bower_components/react/react.js'),
        }
    }
}


webpack prod js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')

const paths = require('./paths')
const common = require('./webpack.common')

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: false,
  output: {
    path: paths.build,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 2,
              sourceMap: false,
              modules: false,
            },
          },
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Extracts CSS into separate files
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin(), '...'],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
          //chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'runtime',
    },
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
})

i tried change webpack config js, paths and rules. but its not works.
also guides for webpack 4 generally. and webpack docs is very complex, so i trying on boilterplate

Webpack generates a JS file for each resource defined in the entry option.
So works Webpack.
To remove generated empty JavaScript files you can use the webpack-remove-empty-scripts plugin.
Install
npm install webpack-remove-empty-scripts --save-dev

Usage
Add the plugin to webpack.config.js:
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    // removes the empty `.js` files generated by webpack
    new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
    ...
  ],
  ...
};



great! thank you!
i guess its not works for dev / devserver mode right?

the plugin works independent from the mode, but it should be used in only production mode for the performance reason

i got it. thank you @biodiscus !
